# how to run two statements in one funcation

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to delete from two tables using one function.

Controller code:

```
public function userdelete()
    {
        $u_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
                $lr_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $returndata = $this->user_model->user_delete($u_id, $lr_id);
               
                
             
        if($returndata) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('successmessage', 'user deleted successfully..');
            redirect('users');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('warningmessage', 'Something went wrong..Try again');
            redirect('users');
        }
}
```

Modle code:

```
public function user_delete($lr_id, $u_id ) { 
        
        
                   return $this->db->delete('login_roles',['lr_id'=>$lr_id]);
           
           
           
                   return $this->db->delete('login',['u_id'=>$u_id]);
               
               
                }
```

I'm able to delete only from the first table but not the other one. this is working :

`return $this->db->delete('login_roles',['lr_id'=>$lr_id]); but not  return $this->db->delete('login',['u_id'=>$u_id]);.`

Comment: it never reaches the second `$this->db->delete` since its returns after executing the first one. Remove the `return`.

Comment: Didn't you ask this some hours ago? I remember having commented there...

Comment: What does `delete()` return? Because you can't pass it down to `user_delete()` if you have several values, unless you create an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment you have to remove the first return.
You should compute the two results :

```
public function user_delete($lr_id, $u_id ) { 
    $delete1Response = $this->db->delete('login_roles',['lr_id'=>$lr_id]);
    $delete2Response = $this->db->delete('login',['u_id'=>$u_id]);
    return ($delete1Response AND $delete2Response);
}
```

It will returns `true` only if both are deleted

You even can go further and :

```
 public function user_delete($lr_id, $u_id ) { 
    $delete1Response = $this->db->delete('login_roles',['lr_id'=>$lr_id]);
    $delete2Response = $this->db->delete('login',['u_id'=>$u_id]);
    return (object)array('role' => $delete1Response, 'user' => $delete2Response);
 }
```

Then you can access to data like that :

```
$response = user_delete(...);
if ($response->role AND $response->user) {
    // All fine
} else {
    // One or both failed.
    // Display error or do something
}
```

Comment: This did work for me thank you for your support. I have been trying all day.

Comment: Nice. Could you accept my answer

Comment: I have another question. how to make the checkbox to send the value of 0 to the table when unchecked. because now it can only send the value of 1.                        <input type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if(isset($userdetails[0]['lr_vech_list'])) { echo ($userdetails[0]['lr_geofence_delete']==1 ? 'checked' : ''); } ?> name="permissions[lr_geofence_delete]" class="custom-control-input" id="lr_geofence_delete">

Answer (score 0):

It never reaches the second $this->db->delete since its returns after executing the first one. Try:

```
public function user_delete($lr_id, $u_id ) { 
    if($this->db->delete('login_roles',['lr_id'=>$lr_id])){
        //success, try the next one      
        return $this->db->delete('login',['u_id'=>$u_id]);
    }
    //failed
    return false;
}
```